# ¿Como colocar un elemento div al final del contenido usando la Grid CSS?

Tags: html, css, div, flexbox, grid

Estoy creando un pdf en el backend utilizando playwright para procesarlo y para el formato y diseño HTML y CSS. Uso Handlebars para el procesamiento de los datos.

Pero mi problema es de diseño, quiero poder colocar la firma del documento siempre al final del documento, a donde termina, no lo quiero poner como footer pero quiero que se a medida el contenido crezca la firma se mantenga fija al final de la pagina.

[image: Ejemplo de la posicion de la firma]

No quiero usar posicionamiento absoluto/relativo porque eso haria que los elementos estuvieran fuera. Entonces estoy buscando la forma de hacer que el contenido de la firma se muestre al final del HTML siempre usando flexbox o grid

Error actual

[image: Como se muestra el error actual]

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

html,
:host {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  -o-tab-size: 4;
  tab-size: 4;
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  font-variation-settings: normal;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  print-color-adjust: exact;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
}

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.table-card-body tr,
.table-card-body td {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.table-card {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.paddingCard {
  padding-left: 4px !important;
  padding-right: 4px !important;
}

th {
  font-size: 13pt !important;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute !important;
}

.relative {
  position: relative !important;
}

.inset-0 {
  inset: 0px !important;
}

.inset-y-0 {
  top: 0px !important;
  bottom: 0px !important;
}

.left-16 {
  left: 4rem !important;
}

.pointer-events-none {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}

.left-8 {
  left: 2rem !important;
}

.z-10 {
  z-index: 10 !important;
}

.mt-1 {
  margin-top: 0.25rem !important;
}

.mt-3 {
  margin-top: 1.8rem !important;
}

.mt-20 {
  margin-top: 3rem
  !important;
}

.mt-40 {
  margin-top: 10rem
  !important;
}

.ml-6 {
  margin-left: 1.5rem
  !important;
}

.page-footer,
.page-footer-space {
  height: 70px;
}

.mt-3 {
  margin-top: 0.75rem
  !important;
}

.mb-1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem !important;
}

.mt-20 {
  margin-top: 4rem
  !important;
}

.flex {
  display: flex !important;
}

.inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex !important;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}

.grid {
  display: grid !important;
}

.h-10 {
  height: 2.5rem !important;
}

.pr-2 {
  padding-right: 0.5rem
  !important;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.h-auto {
  height: auto !important;
}

.zoom-in {
  zoom: 1.2 !important;
}

.w-1\/2 {
  width: 50% !important;
}

.w-\[125px\] {
  width: 125px !important;
}

.w-\[80px\] {
  width: 40PX;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.max-w-\[180px\] {
  max-width: 180px !important;
}

.flex-auto {
  flex: 1 1 auto !important;
}

.grid-cols-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr)) !important;
}

.grid-cols-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr)) !important;
}

.grid-cols-4 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr)) !important;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid !important;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr !important;
  grid-column-gap: 0.25rem !important;
  padding-top: 0.25rem !important;
}

.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 1rem !important;
}

.htmlForm td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 9px;
}

.overflow-wrap {
  text-wrap: wrap;
}

.object-fit {
  object-fit: cover !important;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column !important;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center !important;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center !important;
}

.justify-between {
  justify-content: space-between !important;
}

.justify-end {
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

.gap-1 {
  gap: 0.25rem !important;
}

.gap-2 {
  gap: 0.5rem !important;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100px !important;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100px !important;
}

.h-\[128px\] {
  height: 128px !important;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important
}

.mt-2,
.my-2 {
  margin-top: .5rem !important
}

.m-auto {
  margin: auto !important
}

.border {
  border-width: 1px !important;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important
}

.border-b {
  border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
}

.border-dark {
  border-color: #343a40 !important
}

.border-collapse {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}

.w-auto {
  width: auto !important
}

.border-r-\[3px\] {
  border-right-width: 3px !important;
}

.border-gray-200 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1 !important;
  border-color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-border-opacity)) !important;
}

.border-gray-100 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1 !important;
  border-color: rgb(230 230 228 / var(--tw-border-opacity)) !important;
}

.bg-gray-200 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1 !important;
  background-color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-bg-opacity)) !important;
}

.bg-black {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1 !important;
  background-color: rgb(44 43 48 / var(--tw-bg-opacity)) !important;
}

.bg-gray-100 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1 !important;
  background-color: rgb(230 230 228 / var(--tw-bg-opacity)) !important;
}

.bg-white {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1 !important;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity)) !important;
}

.firma-label {
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 9px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px !important;
}

.FormContent img {
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 0.3rem 0rem !important;
}

.p-1 {
  padding: 0.25rem !important;
}

.px-1 {
  padding-left: 0.25rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.25rem !important;
}

.px-2 {
  padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
}

.px-3 {
  padding-left: 0.75rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.75rem !important;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-top: 0.25rem !important;
}

.px-2 {
  padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
}

.px-8 {
  padding-left: 2rem !important;
  padding-right: 2rem !important;
}

.py-1\.5 {
  padding-top: 0.375rem !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.375rem !important;
}

.pl-2 {
  padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
}

.pr-2 {
  padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right !important;
}

.text-\[10px\] {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}

.text-\[8px\] {
  font-size: 8px !important;
}

.font-bold {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

.font-normal {
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.leading-2 {
  line-height: 11px !important;
}

.leading-3 {
  line-height: .75rem !important;
}

.leading-\[2\.5\] {
  line-height: 11.5px !important;
}

.leading-\[normal\] {
  line-height: normal !important;
}

.gray-10 {
  background-color: #D3D3D3
}

.text-black {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1 !important;
  color: rgb(44 43 48 / var(--tw-text-opacity)) !important;
}

.text-gray-800 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1 !important;
  color: rgb(79 79 81 / var(--tw-text-opacity)) !important;
}

.text-pink-dark {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1 !important;
  color: rgb(242 124 124 / var(--tw-text-opacity)) !important;
}

.text-white {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1 !important;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity)) !important;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 4px 8px !important;
}

.text-nowrap {
  text-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.pb-1 {
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem !important;
}

.justify-start {
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/solicitud.styles.css">
</head>

<body class='bg-white flex flex-col h-full zoom-in'>
  <table class="border-collapse">
    <header class='w-full relative'>
      <svg class='absolute inset-y-0 left-16 pointer-events-none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='234px' height='56px' viewBox='0 0 234 48' fill='none'>
                    <path d='M0 -24H234L226 -16L162 48H0V-24Z' fill='#E6E6E4' />
                </svg>

      <svg class='absolute inset-y-0 left-8 pointer-events-none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='234px' height='64px' viewBox='0 0 234 56' fill='none'>
                    <path d='M0 -16H234L226 -8L162 56H0V-16Z' fill='#4F4F51' />
                </svg>

      <svg class='absolute inset-0 pointer-events-none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='234px' height='72px' viewBox='0 0 234 64' fill='none'>
                    <path d='M0 -8H234L226 0L162 64H0V-8Z' fill='#2C2B30' />
                </svg>

      <img class='h-10 w-[125px] absolute' style="left: 24px !important; bottom:8px !important;" src='' />

      <div class='flex flex-auto items-center justify-between' style="padding: 16px 31px 0px 0px;">
        <div class="w-[125px]"></div>
        <section class="grid grid-cols-2">
          <div class='border-r-[3px] border-gray-200 pr-2 flex justify-end'>
            <div class=' h-10 w-[80px]'>
              <img style="object-fit: cover;" src='' />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='pl-2 text-right text-[8px] flex items-center leading-[normal]'>
            <div>
              <b>Código:</b> B-24-2-0243
              <br />
              <b>Fecha recepción:</b> 14/02/2024
              <br />
              <b>Fecha emisión:</b> 15/02/2024
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </header>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="px-8" style="border: none !important">
          <div class="mt-4 flex flex-auto flex-col h-full gap-4">
            <div class="inline-flex flex-col gap-2">
              <div class='bg-black py-1.5 text-center text-[10px] font-bold uppercase text-white leading-[normal]'>
                Biopsia Vejiga
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- Contenido de las secciones -->
        <td class="px-8">
          <!-- Contenido normal -->
          <div class='flex flex-auto flex-col h-full gap-1' id="tbodyContainer">
            <div class='inline-flex flex-col gap-2'>
              <div class='grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-1 px-2'>
                <div class='text-black font-bold text-[10px] mb-1  leading-[normal]'><span class='text-pink-dark font-normal'>Paciente:</span> MARIA ARGENTINA DERAS PEREZ.
                </div>

                <div class='text-black font-bold text-[10px] mb-1 leading-[normal]'><span class='text-pink-dark font-normal'>Médico
                                            remitente:</span> Bessy Rivera,Jessica Sánchez
                </div>

                <div class='flex flex-col gap-0'>
                  <p class='text-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'>
                    <b>Identidad:</b> 0414198800035
                  </p>
                  <p class='text-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Edad:</b> 38 años
                  </p>
                  <p class='text-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Género:</b> F
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div class='flex flex-col'>
                  <p class='text-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Material        
                                                estudiado:</b> Pruebas
                  </p>
                  <p class='text-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Sitio
                                                de la toma:</b> Pruebas
                  </p>
                  <p class='text-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Diagnóstico     
                                                clínico:</b> Colon- Resección:</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <table style="border: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;" class="border-collapse">
              <thead class="bg-gray-100 mt-4">
                <tr>
                  <th style="border: 0 !important; text-align: left !important;" class="text-black px-2 py-1.5 font-bold uppercase leading-[normal] text-[8px]">
                    DESCRIPCIÓN MACROSCÓPICA
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="table-card-body">
                <tr>
                  <td class="htmlForm">
                    <p
                      class="paragraphsSpace">Muestras representativas a estudio de la siguiente manera: A - E c&#xe9;rvix-tercio superior de vagina</p>
                      <div class="mt-3 grid grid-cols-3 gap-2">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-1">
                          <div class="w-full h-[128px] overflow-hidden"><img class="e-resize e-rte-image e-imginline e-rte-drag-image object-fit" src="1707932974991.webp" alt="none" /></div>
                          <p class="leading-2 text-[10px] max-w-[180px] overflow-wrap mt-1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-1">
                          <div class="w-full h-[128px] overflow-hidden"><img class="e-resize e-rte-image e-imginline object-fit" src="1707932974991.webp" alt="none" /></div>
                          <p class="leading-2 text-[10px] max-w-[180px] overflow-wrap mt-1" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
              <tbody class="table-card-body">
                <tr>
                  <td class="htmlForm">
                    <p class="paragraphsSpace">LESION DE MAMA IZQUIERDA</p>
                    <p class="paragraphsSpace">-INMUNOHISTOQUIMICA</p>
                    <p class="paragraphsSpace">-RECEPTOR DE ESTR&#xd3;GENO: POSITIVO (PUNTAJE DE ALLRED 7)</p>
                    <p class="paragraphsSpace">-RECEPTOR DE PROGESTERONA: POSITIVO (PUNTAJE DE ALLRED 6)</p>
                    <p class="paragraphsSpace">-HER 2: POSITIVO 3+ .</p>
                    <p class="paragraphsSpace">COMENTARIO: CARCINOMA DUCTAL INFILTRANTE, RECEPTOR DE ESTR&#xd3;GENOS POSITIVOS PUNTAJE DE ALLRED 7, RECEPTOR DE PROGEST&#xc1;GENOS POSITIVO PUNTAJE DE ALLRED 6, HER2 NEU POSITIVO 3+. CORRELACIONAR CON HISTORIA CL&#xcd;NICA DE PACIENTE.</p>
                    <div
                      class="mt-3 grid grid-cols-3 gap-2" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 !important;">
          <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <div style=" align-items: flex-end !important; flex-grow: 1 !important;">
    <div style="background: red;" class='flex justify-center items-center'>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <div class='w-full border-b border-dark'>
          <img src='data:image/png;base64,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'
            alt='firma médico' class='w-auto m-auto' style="height: 40px;" />
        </div>
        <p class='firma-label pt-1 text-[8px]'>Dr. Un doctor</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<footer class="footer" style="width: 100% !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">

  <style>
    #footer {
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
  </style>

  <div style="width: 100% !important;">
    <div style="display: flex !important; justify-content: space-between !important; align-items: center !important;">
      <div style="width: 70% !important; margin-left: 24px !important; padding: 8px !important; display:flex !important;  align-items:center !important; height:32px !important;">
        <div style="font-size: 8px; width: 90% !important;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p style="display: flex; font-size: 8px !important; background-color: #F7F7F7 !important; padding: 4px 16px !important; margin-right: 24px !important;">
        Pág: 1-2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; color: #F7F7F7 !important; justify-content: space-between !important; align-items: center !important; background: url('data:image/png;base64,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'); background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-size: 100% !important; height: 48px !important;">
      <p style="font-size: 9.2px !important; max-width: 54% !important; margin-left:26px !important;">
        Dirección
      </p>

      <div style="margin-right: 80px !important;">
        <div style="font-size: 9.2px !important; height: fit-content !important; text-wrap: nowrap !important; background: #4F4F51; border-radius: 80px !important; padding: 4px 16px !important;">
          B-24-2-0243
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Ejecutando el snippet, ¿se ve tal como esperas? Por otra parte: espero que esos no sean datos ni firmas reales...

Comment: No,, no son firmas reales, son de ejemplo. Es que en el snippet no se nota, hare un stackblitz para poder duplicar el problema